# Change in one field is reflected in others with same key in Vuejs multidimentional form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a multidimentional form in vuejs with fields for each language.

```
<v-tab-item v-for="language in languages" :key="language">
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">
      <v-text-field
        label="Title"
        v-model="title[language]"
       ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>
   </v-row>
   <v-row>
     <v-col cols="6">
       <v-textarea
        label="Description"
        v-model="description[language]"
       ></v-textarea>
     </v-col>
   </v-row>
</v-tab-item>
```

This is languages array

```
languages: ['first-language', 'second-language', 'third-language']
```

Now when i add any text in title field with keyboard same text gets added in description field also.. is there any other way to define `v-model` for multidimentional form?

Comment: Hmm, I tried to recreate your issue, but it's working for me. Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/nicolasdurant/pen/ZEBXJjm How did you define title and description in your data?

Comment: Yes issue was from my side that i was assigning same object to both `title` and `description` in `data` object and as both was refrencing same object so both was changing  at same time.. i change assignment to .. `{ ...langObject }` so not they are not refrencing same object.